# software serial not working with my esp8266

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am not able to use esp8266 wifi module on arduino uno using software serial, the problem is that i am not getting correct output. But i am able work with Arduino mega which has additional hardware serial tx-rx pairs. how to make it work on uno?

I used lm1117 voltage divider for esp8266, tried other voltage dividers(1k+2k), nothing seems to work on uno and nano.

Here is the output i am getting

```
 AT+RST


OK

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst c`use:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 1386, room 16 
t`il 4
chkstm 0x89
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, rtail 4
e 
t`ilcn1e IeKo
ŒÕ(j5�!
-€3%1…

j
äsl��oÿ
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

ready
Aj+CWMOBD=3


OK
AR+CWJAP="Max_Regul]®ÅªÖKb½�AAÅ¢ª²R‰j
WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+¨R5UIVER=1,<0


OK
Server Ready
```

Comment: How do you supply your ESP8266?

Comment: I use usb cable to supply arduino board, and i use lm1117 3.3v ic to convert 5v on the arduino to esp 3.3v vcc.

Comment: Do you use any timers in your Software? It could be a Timer conflictwith the software serial libary.

Comment: What timers..? No, i dont think so, but my code works in mega. Now how is that possible.

Comment: Look at this: https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Timers-Arduino

Comment: From the info the Arduino uno has 3Timers. The relation between timers and PWM outputs is:

Pins 5 and 6: controlled by timer0
Pins 9 and 10: controlled by timer1
Pins 11 and 3: controlled by timer2...so are you suggesting that i shouldnot use any of these pins for softwareserial library.

Comment: Presently i am using pins 2 and 3 for SoftwareSerial, and pin 9 for controlling Infrared LED. Are these conflicting with each other..?

Comment: You should know, which timer your softwareSerial is using. There could be a conflict with other used timers. An easy way to find out: Just use your softwareserial. Then add stepby step other softwareparts.

Comment: changing software serial pins didnt solve my problem..

Comment: You should use external 3.3v supply, because you need 200 mA for the Esp module. Maybe it worked for mega because can handle more current.